# How to use ericbarnes/CodeIgniter-Events?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in CodeIgniter  and  trying to use the library to manage the events in the application which i am currently working on . After a little google i found the  library mentioned below  as the best one.

https://github.com/ericbarnes/CodeIgniter-Events/blob/master/libraries/events.php

But i don't know how to use it.. well i have coded a little bit by which user can add,view,update and delete event.But i want to manage the event in such a way that if the user add event then the event should be hided  automatically from the view part after when the time 
for the event is finished... Can i do it by the libaray that i had mentioned above ?? oR anyone can tell me the best event library....

Comment: `user can add,view,update and delete event` do you mean calendar event ?

Comment: yep somewhat like that ...

Answer (score 2):

I think you got something wrong. That library is designed to handle events, particularly to notify your application when something else in your application happened you want to handle.

Based on your question I guess you want to implement a functionality that allows you to manage events like parties, meetings or stuff like that.

You will hardly find any ready-to-go solutions since a framework (and it's additional libraries) is only a toolkit to simplify the process of development.

To give you a quickstart I just assembled something for you. CodeIgniter provides a calendar library which tries to simplify the effort of creating a calendar system.

So let's create three files. A controller, a model and a viewfile for our calendar template.

**application/controllers/calendar.php**

```
<?php

class Calendar extends CI_Controller{

    /**
     * The constructor loads our calendar library and passes 
     * our custom calendar template to it. Also we load 
     * the calendar model where the events will be pulled from
     * later on.
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $calendar_conf['template'] = $this->load->view('calendar_template', null, true);
        $this->load->library('calendar', $calendar_conf);

        $this->load->model('calendar_model');
    }

    /**
     * Pulls events from our Calendar_Model and displays the
     * events
     */

    public function index()
    {
        $year = date('Y');
        $month = date('m');

        $events = $this->calendar_model->get_events($year, $month);
        echo $this->calendar->generate($year, $month, $events);

    }

}
```

**application/models/calendar_model.php**

```
<?php

class Calendar_Model extends CI_Model{

    private $events = array(
        '2013' => array(
            '07' => array(
                3  => 'Meeting with Mr. Smith',
                7  => 'Big Party tonight bro!',
                13 => 'Something Big will happen here ;)',
            )
        )
    );

    /**
     * Gets events of a given year and month
     * your probably want to pull your events 
     * from a database.
     */

    public function get_events($y, $m)
    {
        if(!isset($this->events[$y][$m]))
            return null;
        return $this->events[$y][$m];
    }

}
```

Finally let's create our calendar template

**application/views/calendar_template.php**

```
{table_open}<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4">{/table_open}

{heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}

{heading_previous_cell}<th><a href="{previous_url}">&lt;&lt;</a></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
{heading_title_cell}<th colspan="{colspan}">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}
{heading_next_cell}<th><a href="{next_url}">&gt;&gt;</a></th>{/heading_next_cell}

{heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}

{week_row_start}<tr>{/week_row_start}
{week_day_cell}<td>{week_day}</td>{/week_day_cell}
{week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}

{cal_row_start}<tr>{/cal_row_start}
{cal_cell_start}<td>{/cal_cell_start}

{cal_cell_content}<a href="#" title="{content}">{day}</a>{/cal_cell_content}
{cal_cell_content_today}<div class="highlight"><a href="{content}">{day}</a></div>{/cal_cell_content_today}

{cal_cell_no_content}{day}{/cal_cell_no_content}
{cal_cell_no_content_today}<div class="highlight">{day}</div>{/cal_cell_no_content_today}

{cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}

{cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}
{cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}

{table_close}</table>{/table_close}
```

The controller loads our model where the event data is stored and passes the data to CI's native Calendar library. Then we display the calendar itself. The model itself is dedicated to hold the event data and to provide methods to read and (not implemented here, but you might want to) write events.

Finally we have our viewfile which serves as our calendar template. It uses template variables which are given by CodeIgniter. You can take a read here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/calendar.html

Of course that's just a possible fractional part of a calendar application. For example our events are not capable to hold more than a string of data. Once you got better with CodeIgniter you might want to extend the native calendar class to allow the storage of arrays.

But I think it's a good start for now. If you have any further questions on this don't hesitate to ask.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Dear Thomas , Thanx for your answer.. But can i do it without using calender template?? one question how can i subtract two dates ???

Comment: How do you want to display a calendar without a template? :) You can of course edit the template the way you want but you will defenitely need kind of a display layer. PHP provides a powerful Object (DateTime) which will help you to work with dates. Have a look on this: http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.sub.php

Comment: My application goes like this..user can add,edit,delete the events he /she had  created.the only thing i need is "if the event date is 11-july-2013 then after this date the event shouldn't be displayed in user view .. :)